# docker and python using symfony process

Tags: python, laravel, laradock, symfony-process

I am using Laradock and want to be able to run a python script from my laravel app using Symfony Process. From inside the root on my container I can run "python3 script_name.py arg1" and it runs just fine. pip list shows all modules needed. When I run it from inside Laravel, it tells me:

```
"import pymysql ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'"
```

I have used a non-docker Laravel app to do this just fine, using:

```
  $script = storage_path().'/app/script.py';
            $process = new Process('python3 '. $script." ".session('division'));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

On *nix make sure that PYTHONPATH is configured correctly for all users or try to set full path to python3.

How to check

At first your php user

```
php -r "print shell_exec( 'whoami' );" // somebody
```

When run

```
su somebody python3 script_name.py arg1
```

Comment: ugh i got "ERR > su: must be run from a terminal" this is the worst